# Zend Framework: Zend_Db_Select - how to join custom subquery table?

Tags: zend-framework

```
$select->joinRight(array('i' => '(SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY image_id)'),'i.ad_id = '. $main .'.id',$imarray);
```

Like that doesn't work. Subquery getting inside quotes.

Like that:

```
RIGHT JOIN `(SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY image_id)` AS `i` ON i.ad_id = a.id
```

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use

```
$select->joinRight(
    array('i' => new Zend_Db_Expr('(SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY image_id)')),
    'i.ad_id = '. $main .'.id',
    $imarray
);
```

Comment: I thought that, but I was in good mood. That why it's not RTFM :D

Comment: BTW: I think that if you replaced the string with Zend_Db_Select object it would work as well....

Answer (score 5):

I feel This is easier to read and navigate...

```
      $sub = $this->select()
            ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
            ->from(array('i' => 'images'), array('*'))
            ->order('i.image_id');

$select = $this->select()
             ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
             ->from(array('m' => 'MAIN_TABLE'), array('*'))
             ->joinRight(array('i' => $sub), 'i.ad_id = m.id', array('*'));

   return $this->select($select);
```